# How to make new column for counting distinct values in DataTable c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have DataTable with 3 columns: name, description and date

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuMew.png)

I also have ComboBox and on his event I need to filter datas in table, based on dates.

After using that filter I have to have only distinct values with number how many times that name appear in original table, like this:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB8S4.png)

I have to do this in c#. I was trying with Linq but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Post what you have tried. No one can help without code.

Comment: I haven't tried a lot in my code, just filled table and datagridview with it. I think my code isn't useful.

Comment: We could tell you where you went wrong if you posted code. Also, it is no recommended that you post images, post actual text.